# How to add extra filter and columns into existing saved searches while loading in Netsuite 2.0

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I have the following SuiteScript 2.0 code in a UserEvent where I would like to add an additional filter and columns to the loaded saved search.
A filter is working properly but how to get column value from Array which is added as an extra column in Saved search.

```
var filters = [];
filters.push(
['memo', 'is', 'Updated']
);
var filters = [];
filters.push(
['memo', 'is', 'Updated']
);

var columnsCust = [];
columnsCust.push(search.createColumn({
name: 'trandate'
}));

var mySearch = search.load({
id: 'customsearch_so_savedsearch'
});

//Add filters
mySearch.filterExpression = filters;
var filtersResult = mySearch.filterExpression;

//Add columns
mySearch.column = columnsCust;
var columnResult = mySearch.column;

var searchResult = mySearch.run().getRange({start: 0,end: 10});
for (var i = 0; i < searchResult.length; i++) 
{
var date = searchResult[i].getValue({name: 'trandate'});
log.debug('date::' + date);      //date::null
//it gives transactionnumber value Because this column exist in Saved 
  //search.
    var transactionnumber = searchResult[i].getValue({name: 'transactionnumber'});
log.debug('transactionnumber::' + transactionnumber);   //transactionnumber::112513
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To add extra columns, filters or filterExpressions in a search object, firsrt you need to fetch the object from search-object and then update it.

For Search Columns
    var searchColumns = mySearch.columns;

```
searchColumns.push(AdditionalColumns);

mySearch.columns = searchColumns;
```

For Search Filters

```
var searchFilters = mySearch.filters;

searchFilters.push(additionalFilters);

mySearch.filters = searchFilters;
```

For FilterExpressions

```
var searchFilterExpression = mySearch.filterExpression;

// push operator if searchObject contains filters
if (searchFilterExpression.length > 0) {
  searchFilterExpression.push('and');
}

searchFilterExpression.push(additionalFilterExpression);

mySearch.filterExpression = searchFilterExpression;
```

**Note:** Check [this](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4392315904.html) out for further reading.